# API to get all pincodes inside a radius

Tags: python, django, google-api, maps

I'm working on a python application where we need to get all the pincodes within a specific radius.
We have a base location and a radius of 10Km is drawn from this base pincode.

Do we have any API where this can be achieved?

FYA - Mainly looking for Indian PostalCodes.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to my mind is the Google Maps API, under this link you can find the relevant guide for it: https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/client-library

I guess that you will need to sign up for google maps api key and enable the place search feature for your key. I think this Place Search feature is all you need for your task.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).